# Intel turbo boost and multi core performance relation

Tags: c, performance, x86

I have seen a recommendation to disable turbo boost for multi core performance improvement.[here, section 7.1.2](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/nic_perf_intel_platform.html).This is the exact wording from link:**Disable Turbo Boost to ensure the performance scaling increases with the number of cores.**
  I always thought more clock speed means more ups and more performance. So turbo boost should always help or at least shouldn't harm performance of system. But this recommendation is very surprising. Any thoughts on this point?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions on that page look reasonable for getting consistent benchmark results, but terrible for ongoing use.

- *Disable all power saving options such as: Power performance tuning, CPU P-State, CPU C3 Report and CPU C6 Report.*  This will make your CPU waste huge amounts of power when it's idle.
- *Select Performance as the CPU Power and Performance policy.* This will probably also hurt idle power consumption, and maybe also light-load performance
- *Disable Turbo Boost to ensure the performance scaling increases with the number of cores.*

**Disabling turbo will indeed make the performance ratio between single-core and many-core more predictable (scaling), but it does so by slowing down single-core, not by speeding up multi-core.**

Desktop/mobile CPUs also [turbo with multiple cores active](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#Desktop_processors) (to a lower frequency), but IDK if Xeons do that.

---

Only follow those suggestions if you want to verify that performance behaves the way you expect when you take CPU power saving out of the equation.  **Put them all back to normal after!!**

A 1% increase in performance isn't worth a 20% increase in power consumption.  Running hot all the time means less thermal headroom for Turbo, so disabling P-states and so on could lead to a decrease in actual performance, esp. for a slightly bursty workload.

The [IDF talk about Skylake Power Management](http://myeventagenda.com/sessions/0B9F4191-1C29-408A-8B61-65D7520025A8/7/5#sessionID=155) pointed out some gains in a few benchmarks (e.g. JavaScript) from saving more power between bursts, so it could turbo more of the time when there was work to do.  (Skylake can reclock itself much faster than Broadwell, because it can do all its own power management internally instead of having the OS choose the clock speed for levels below max/turbo.)

Answer (score 0):

you're misinterpreting. Read closely. Performance "scales" means you take twice the number of cores, you get twice the performance.

However, turbo boosting will only work on single cores at a time – so when you take N non-turbo-boosting cores, you get N times the performane of a single non-boosting one, but if you take M turbo-boosting cores, you will only get M times the performance of a non-boosting core; since that is less than M times the performance of a boosting core, Scaling breaks, but not the absolute performance increase, though that will diminish relatively with the number of cores.

Comment: Your statement - "turbo boosting will only work on single cores at a time" is not clear to me. Can you bit more explain this point. My understanding is if turbo boost is enabled, all cores will run on highest possible frequency provided thermal conditions are met.

Comment: Actually, Turbo can boost multiple cores at once.  The max single-core turbo is a bit higher than the max dual or quad-core turbo, but for some CPUs with a low TDP, there is power / thermal headroom to turbo multiple cores for short periods.  e.g. for [Skylake Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#Desktop_processors), 6600k 3.5GHz sustained can single-core turbo to 3.9GHz, but only to 3.6GHz for quad-core.

Comment: @PeterCordes exactly; it makes no sense to use turbo boost in a "I need the performance boost continually" scenario, as that will just lead to thermal throttling later on, and that "higher than usual – lower than usual – higher than usual …" clocking scheme definitely doesn't help system behaviour.